# replacing line in txt file AFTER specific line

Tags: batch-file, text, replace, edit

demo file below. in group [two] i want to toggle 'enable group' between 0 & 1 without affecting the rest of the file, line returns included.

Problems i've found is there are REPLICATED LINES; 'enable group' being one of them so i cant get findstr to work.

Editing a specific LINE NUMBER wont work in this case because even though all files follow this format group [three] is often found on different lines.

all [abc] titles are unique

i want to use only batch if possible. thanks

```
; this is file information
; stuff
; last edited Thu Mar 23 01:13:18 2017

[general]
I/O = AB-1234
second line = 0
third line = 1

[i/o one]
enable group = 0
enable board = 0
memory size = 0

[two]
enable group = 0

[three]
enable group = 0
enable board = 0
memory size = 0
```

Comment: How much are you willing to pay? Do not confuse SO with a free code writing service! Please learn [ask]!

Comment: @aschipfl sorry mate didnt mean to offend anyone, im very new to this and was just chasing some direction. worked it out for myself. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

after another solid day and nights reading and research i have worked out a way! though it might seem simple to some this is all very new to me. basically im searching for what line number the two heading is on and modifying the line after

```
echo off
cls
set /p number=set 1 or 0: 

for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i /n /c:"two" "test.txt"') do (
set /a line=%%a+1
) >nul

>"test.tmp" (
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /v /n /c:"FileDoesNotContainThis" "test.txt"') do (
if "%%~a"=="%line%" (
echo Enable Group = %number%
) ELSE (
echo.%%b
)
)
)
MOVE "test.tmp" "test.txt" >nul
```

i have a basic understanding of what i wrote, any questions glad to help